# How to minimize a window using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to minimize my web driver(chrome driver)in java and I have used:

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, -1000));
```

but there's an error saying:

> can not find the symbol Point

What is needed to be done? Dose the Point need to be declared or headers need to be included?

Comment: you should tell us which program language you used

Comment: Why do you want to minimize the browser? What is your exact use case?

Comment: @DebanjanB i have made an project containing 8 websites which will scrap historical and live market data for different user input (the company u want data about and the time period) .. now i have integrated the whole in a single program and made a simple batch file to for cmd user interface ... now when the input is given and webdriver is launched the cmd interface or the console is going behind the webdriver window so i need to minimize the  web driver for smooth console view... i have already done it by robot class but i want to know if any other means are possible ...

Comment: Dimension will change the window size and it may affect the automation i think but that driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, -1000)); may work but i dont know how to make it work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be

```
import java.lang.Object;  
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
```

these must be imported to make

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, -1000));
```

this will place the window out of visible range

for Dimensions

```
    import java.lang.Object;  
    import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
```

and the code be

```
Dimension d=new Dimension(200, 300);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

this will only resize the window by Dimension( x, y)

we can also use robot class

```
import java.awt.Robot;  
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

and the code for this is (ALT+Space+N)

```
        `   Robot robot=new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
            Thread.sleep(300);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);`
```

this will minimise the window

Answer (score 0):

Use the setSize(Dimension dim) method of Webdriver.Window.

```
driver.window.setSize(new Dimension(0,0))
```

Comment: not working ?? cant find dimension .. dose it need any header ?? @Grasshopper

Comment: What do u mean cant find dimension? It is a java class, u have to import it.

Comment: the header please :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Dimension d=new Dimension(200, 300);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium without opening the browser in the first place :)

```
//import the selenium web driver
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
//setting chrome options to be headless so that chrome browser doesn't pop up
var chromeOptions = {
    'args': ["--headless"]
};
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium `Dimension(int w, int h)` method with (0, 0) dimension.

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new org.openqa.selenium.Point(0, 0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(0, 0));
```